# Foundation equivalent of Twitter Bootstrap modal?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, zurb-foundation

I am converting a simple webapp from Bootstrap to Foundation framework. What is the equivalent of

```
$(...).modal()
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It's the reveal component:

https://get.foundation/sites/docs/reveal.html

```html
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>


<p><button class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</button></p>
```

```js
$(document).foundation();
```